# Z-Layering Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

It's is possible to "stack" fragments on top of each other?

Just tried to do this without really thinking about it and everything got kinda crazy.
I can (and probably should) create a ViewGroup instead if it's not possible, but I was just wondering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. E.g. by wrapping them inside a `FrameLayout` like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.package.FragmentOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    <fragment android:name="com.package.FragmentTwo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

</FrameLayout>
```

The z-index depends on the order of the children within the layout. In this example `FragmentTwo` is above `FragmentOne` because it's the second child.

Comment: Have you actually tried this and got it working? I was making a navigation fragment and made sure it was on top in my RelativeLayout, but it messed the layout up entirely.

Comment: @FrankSposaro Yes, tested it in a small sample project before answering. [Here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17220543/Test.zip) is the project, see if it helps you.